# An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: unable to get local issuer certificate" while create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have the following installed on my windows machine:

Node : v12.18.4

yarn : 1.19.1

create-react-app: 3.4.1

I navigated to the folder c:\temp and then tried to create react app using the following command:

c:\temp>create-react-app react-test --scripts-version 1.1.5

On executing the above command I see the following error:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Temp\react-test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: unable to get local issuer certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Temp\\react-test\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Temp\react-test has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue

Answer (score 52):

Turn off the strict-ssl on yarn/npm config, and try again

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

or

```
npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

Comment: Yep.  That did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me thank you.

Comment: This is CERTAINLY not a good move in the manner of security. Registries should have valid certificates. If they are self-signed, the user should manually verify them, or a good registry with valid certificates should be the way.

Comment: @thiras What could be the consequences of registries not having valid certificates? Just want to understand the practical dangers of disabling strict-ssl.

Comment: Why should users permanently disable security if only one package is affected? Please update your answer and describe what the commands do and provide the commands necessary for re-enabling security.

Answer (score 14):

Not a big fan disabling strict-ssl.

This worked for me

```
yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: Will this work for yarn? I don't see how this answers the Op's question.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not blindly disabling strict-ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands one by one to resolve the issue.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g
npm config delete registry
```

Answer (score 0):

After try the different options here (safest and unsafest) the problem persist. I solve that **cleaning caches**, specially Yarn; **reboot** & **try again**, and then voila, all works as is expected.